# choosing the methods of the current class and not the inherited class

Tags: java, reflection

Suppose that I have these classes:

```
class A{
  void f();
}

class B extends A{
  void g();
}
```

what will I get when I do:

```
Class.forename("B").getMethods();
```

will I get the methods `f` and `g` ????

if yes, so how to get just the methods of the current class and not it's father class (In this example the method `g()` ) ????

thanks forehead!

Comment: the more question marks a question gets the more robust it looks!

Answer (score 8):

Use [Class.getDeclaredMethods](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredMethods%28%29) instead of getMethods.

> This(methods returned by getDeclaredMethods) includes `public`, `protected`,
>   `default` (package) access, and
>   `private` methods, but excludes
>   inherited methods.

Answer (score 0):

Use getDeclaredMethods() api.

from java api reference -

> Returns an array of Method objects reflecting all the methods declared by the class or interface represented by this Class object. This includes public, protected, default (package) access, and private methods, but excludes inherited methods.